# How to use QtSpeech to access TTS in linux?

Tags: qt4

I am trying to do TTS (Text to Speech ) using Qtspeech in linux. I have downloaded the QtSpeech library. Can anybody suggest me with a simple example program how to use Qtspeech..

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

A quick Internet search surfaced this website:

http://lynxline.com/qtspeech-say-hello-world/

Comment: i had got this.. but i am trying to run the script get-festival.sh what are the supporting files required to run this script?? Please help me if anyone knows the answer..

Comment: `festival` is part of many Linux distributions. If you use Ubuntu or similar, you can try `sudo apt-get install festival-dev speech-tools` instead of using the script `get-festival.sh`

Comment: The curl "some url .... " in get-festival.sh to download festival engine is showing error. So I am following the steps given in the get-festival.sh script..

Answer (score 0):

The standard software used to speech-enable applications on Linux is "**Speech Dispatcher**", which can be found at:
http:// devel.freebsoft.org/speechd

This software is described by the developers as

> "Speech Dispatcher project provides a high-level device independent layer for access to speech synthesis through a simple, stable and well documented interface."

Speech Dispatcher supports these TTS engines:

- List item
- Festival
- Flite
- Espeak
- Cicero
- IBM TTS
- Espeak+MBROLA (through a generic driver)
- Epos (through a generic driver)
- DecTalk software (through a generic driver)
- Cepstral Swift (through a generic driver).  Cepstral provides very high quality voices compatible with x86 and x86_64 systems.  Many voices are offered, and a license for each voice is USD$29.00 (as of 2012-Feb-20).  I think the best voices from Cepstral are David and William.  Stopping by www. cepstral.com/demos and test-driving the voices is well worth the time an very minimal effort.

Speech Dispatcher supports these sound output subsystems:

- List item
- OSS
- ALSA
- PulseAudio
- NAS

In systems that use KDE (which is heavily dependent on Qt), applications connect to Speech Dispatcher by using KDE's text to speech daemon, named "**Jovie**".  Jovie is described by the developers as

> "Jovie KDE Text-to-Speech is a subsystem within the KDE desktop for conversion of text to audible speech."   Jovie is actively under development and is already the standard subsystem for all KDE applications that provide speech output."

More information is available on Jovie at:
http://www.kde.org/applications/utilities/jovie/